# value of a cell in gridview aspx page vb.net web app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview with several columns. I need that, when the user click the button "ver" ("see" in English) I get the value of the cell(1). I inserted a textbox to see if I get the value but it doesn't return any Data. I already read a lot in the net and tried almost everything i read, and still don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone could help me?[image]

The code:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim codigo As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text

    TextBox1.Text = codigo

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly, I got it. I deleted the button "ver" and put a ComandField ---> Select, and now it's working.[image]